How to Login to linkedin using cookies in Python selenium
I am working on building a LinkedIn scraping bot and want to log in using cookies. I am exporting cookies using edit this cookie chrome extension you can find here: editthiscookie. I am using selenium. Below is my code. Can anybody guide me which cookies I should add to make it up and running.
try:
 # Open the URL
    driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/feed')

# Add cookies to the session
try:
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception in cookies.', e)

# Refresh the page
driver.refresh()

# Wait for the page to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body'))
)

# Maximize the window
driver.maximize_window()

